# aws ec2 t2.small vs t2.medium CPU performance

Tags: amazon-ec2, vcpu

Since t2.medium has 2 VCPU and t2.small has 1 VCPU would it be faster as a web server? (Apache/php).

I am wondering if I upgrade if I will gain any performance benefits.

Comment: It depends where your current bottlenecks lie.

Comment: I don't have any bottlenecks and it runs pretty fast. Just curious if it will run faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server will be able to do more work in parallel. If it's just serving static web pages I wouldn't expect much difference. If it's executing php on a loaded server then I would expect some improvement.

Other than cores / RAM, the primary difference between t2 instances is the rate the CPU credit that lets you burst to high performance accumulates. Once you run out of credits you run at the baseline performance for the instance.

You would probably get some improvement in performance moving to new [t3 instances](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/t3/). The t3.small has 2 vCPUs and earns twice as much CPU credits per hour as the t2.small (12 for the t2.small vs 24 for the t3.small). The t3.small is slightly cheaper than the t2.small, and because the hypervisor largely runs in hardware you might get a bit more performance out of it.

Using t3 instances, beware t3.unlimited is turned on by default. This feature enables you to pay more for CPU once you run out of credits. I had a process that sat on 100% CPU for a few days on a t3.micro before I noticed and added alerts, which cost money.